# (Unity) How to add components faster?

Tags: components, unity-game-engine

In **Hierarchy** I have `Gameobject`. `Gameobject` has 126 **`child sprites`**.How to add all of them **Box Collider 2D**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to select all objects with the help of the button ctrl and in the parameters add it